Example contract code for a bonding curve?
I want to create a bonding curve on solana. Are there any good example smart contracts that I can use as a starting point?
I noticed that SPL has a token-swap contracts (https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/b8132db602b3af71c2a2f911ac4245d50c5ed972/token-swap) but wondering if there's one that uses a bonding curve.
Thanks in advance!

You can check out Raydium CPMM which uses X * Y = k
https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-cp-swap/tree/master/programs/cp-swap/src/curve

neat. didn't realized that raydium had a more simplified version of their swap. is this deployed or is this their new version?

This is deployed and it's supposed to be a cheaper alternative to their AMM which requires an open book market id
